# Rails 2.3.10 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm upgrading my working rails 2.3.8 application but i got a strange error.

```
/Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:76:in `block in refresh!': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:45:in `each'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:45:in `refresh!'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:29:in `initialize'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `new'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /Users/davide/Code/giardinilucrezia/config/environment.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:281:in `require'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:281:in `block in load_modules'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:279:in `each'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:279:in `load_modules'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:20:in `setup'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:53:in `start'
        from /Users/davide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

There isn't problem at all with rails 2.3.8.
and the stack trace can't help me. 
Any idea?

I'm using ruby 1.9.2, rails 2.3.10 and bundler.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I looks like [this rails bug](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/6641-vendorgemsourceindexrefresh-fails-when-vendorgems-includes-cvs-directory) is relevant. The short of it is that there's a problem with cvs and svn directories.
to monkey patch, add this to config/preinitializer.rb

```
gem 'rails'
require 'initializer'

module Rails
  class VendorGemSourceIndex

    def version_for_dir(d)
      version = d.split('-').find { |s| s.match(/^\d(\.\d|\.\w+)*$/) }
      Gem::Version.new(version) if version
    end

  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to know what's on line 12 of config/environment.rb and also the command you were trying to run. Presumably script/console or similar.

Comment: the 12 line is Rails::Initializer.run do |config| and the command is script/console

Comment: Looking at rails-2.3.10/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:76 I would suspect that you have some kind of "edge" rails or gems in your vendor directory. Have a look for vendor/rails or vendor/gems/*

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and it turned out to be the `_svn` folder in the `vendor`/`gems` directory.

If that's the case just rename it into `.svn` for now. If you need to update from SVN you will need to rename it back into `_svn`.